# Gyrometer exception handling fails windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, gyroscope

I was trying to access the Gyrometer capabilities from Windows Phone 8 but a First Chance Exception keeps poping when I try to get a handle to the sensor via `Gyrometer::GetDefault()`, that I cannot catch it in a "try catch" block.

The error message is:

> ERROR SensorOpenByInterface: Primary sensor not found.

The msdn clearly states that the default behavior is to return a null pointer if the sensor doesn't exist. I must mention that the manifest has the sensors capability enabled and the app runs on Windows Phone 8 HTC8x Release build.

```
try{ 
     gyrometer = Gyrometer::GetDefault();
    } 
catch(Exception ^Exc){...}.
```

It fails right after the GetDefault, and can't even handle handle the exception.

Comment: You should show the code you use

Comment: try{ gyrometer = Gyrometer::GetDefault();} catch(Exception ^Exc){...}. it fails right after the GetDefault